# How to use recursive query to add columns to a select?

Tags: sql, recursive-query

So I have an accounts table in witch row may or may not have a parent account (0 means it doesn't have a parent):

```
+----+-----------+
| id | parent_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         2 |
|  2 |         0 |
|  3 |         1 |
|  4 |         3 |
|  5 |         4 |
+----+-----------+
```

I was trying to add the top 3 parents for each row, so I would get something like this:

```
+----+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | parent_id | parent_1 | parent_2 | parent_3 |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1 |         2 | 2        | null     | null     |
|  2 |         0 | null     | null     | null     |
|  3 |         1 | 2        | 1        | null     |
|  4 |         3 | 2        | 1        | 3        |
|  5 |         4 | 2        | 1        | 3        |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I figured I can do it with recursive queries, but I haven't managed to build a working query.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use a recursive query to add *columns*.  Each subquery in a recursive CTE needs to have the same set of columns.

Comment: Even if you figure out a way to do it, don't do it. Anything that can call itself more than once can call itself infinite times, which will fill up your server's stack and either be killed or grind the server to a halt.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So I guess I'm tackling this the wrong way. Can you think of a way to achieve my goal in an efficient way? Thanks

Comment: I'd say, add only one column called the tree_path, and String concat the path in there. You can read this article: https://learnsql.com/blog/query-parent-child-tree/, especially the last part: "Generate a Tree View of Hierarchical Data"